# How to delete part of a file and save it in another - using vi

Tags: vi

Say you have a file call stuff.txt and you're editing it in vi.

cat stuff.txt

11233

blah

doesn't matter what

<---------------------pretend your cursor is here

xxcvbbb

dfdfdd

How can you delete from the cursor down and save that in a new file called stuff2.txt without exiting vi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could issue these commands (they're in `ex` mode):

```
:.,$d
:w! stuff2.txt
```

The problem now is that `vi` has an internal representation of `stuff.txt` that is the same as the file `stuff2.txt`.  So, you should issue one more command:

```
:e!
```

That will cause `vi` to read `stuff.txt` again, which effectively undoes the delete.

Comment: Excellent. I have accepted this as the answer. I was looking to have both files be modified so will not use ":e!" but that's great to know!

Comment: `dG` instead of `:.,$d` also works to delete to end of file.   and `u` to undo the delete.